# VS2012 компиляция под Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp, компиляция

Есть рабочий проект, все работает, НО хочется чтобы работало и под Windows XP. Пишу в VS2012 (есть еще VS2015). Решение задачи вроде как нашел -

> Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Platform
>   toolset = Visual Studio 2010(v100)  (Проект->Свойства->Свойства
>   конфигурации->Общие->Набор инструментов платформы = Visual Studio
>   2010(v100))

Ну вот не вижу я "Свойства конфигурации" (или Сonfiguration Properties)...
Ребят, помогите плиз скринами выйти на страничку... 
[image: Вот это вроде как нужно отурыть]

НО я вижу только это (по пути Проект->Свойства->...) и там нет "Свойства конфигурации" ((

[image: Это мое окно, по пути Проект->Свойства->....]

[РЕДАКЦИЯ 1] Ребят, нашел  "Свойства конфигурации" (или Сonfiguration Properties)...Правой кнопкой прям на решении (в обозревателе решений) -> свойства

[image: "Свойства конфигурации" (или Сonfiguration Properties)]

НО к сожалению нет там пункта "Общие" ("General")...

[image: Отсутствие вкладки - Общие]

В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее спасибо за помощь, и ценные советы. ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо просто версию фреймвёрка выставить в 4.0 на этом скрине:

[image]

Comment: а XP 4.0 разве тянет? лет 5 им не пользовался, забылось как-то

Comment: @rdorn, вроде да, если не путаю. VS2010 же?

Comment: и правда https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Всем спасибо, не знал, что XP только до 4 Фреймворка) У меня использовался в коде async-await, то вот пара полезных ссылок в дополнение 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4  2. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async